How do I move PyCharm project folder elsewhere?
I am using PyCharm Community Edition. I have a project folder, that I now need to move to another place on the same PC, on windows 11. I don't seem to be able to do that.
There are a lot of advice for this issue, including JetBrains help pages. They all suggest selecting the project directory in PyCharm and using refactoring (F6) on PyCharm, and moving the project directory elsewhere that way. That would be smart, as it would update all path references etc. in the settings. Here is an example:
Advice on refactoring
All goes basically well when I do this. I can start the refactoring process, some analysis is made and the process ends. No error messages.
But the project folder is still in the same place as before, nothing happened.
What am I doing wrong? Tried contacting JetBrains support, but after they found out I am using Community Edition (assume so) they went quiet.

Not quite sure this is an indication that the refactoring process has been completed, but is the .idea folder created in the target directory?

No, nothing has been created in the target directory.  But JetBrains support finally replied. See my answer to this question.

An update from PyCharm Community Edition 3.1 to 3.1.1 solved this issue. Now project folder-level refactoring, i.e. moving the project folder elsewhere works.
